# Is there no catastrophic backtracking in Go regex?

Tags: regex, go, backtracking

While testing this regex today on regex101.com,
`^([a-z0-9]+(-)*)*([a-z0-9])$`
I got "catastrophic backtracking" error when I tested it on this string:

with flavor PHP:

> aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaT

with flavor Python:

> aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaT

with flavor ECMAScript this longer string got a timeout that 'may be an indication of catastrophic backtracking'

> aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaT

with flavor Java 8 timeout with string

> aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaaT

but flavor Go gave no error or timeout event with much longer such strings. Instead it shows `no match (0.0ms)`

So can I ignore that error/warning when my regex is being used in Go?

I am interested in the reason for this too, but above is my key question.

Comment: Go's stdlib regex engine doesn't support backtracking, so catastrophic backtracking is impossible.

Comment: There is also more information on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE2_(software)

Comment: Change it to `^(?:[a-z0-9]-?)*[a-z0-9]$` and you will not get any bactracking overflow.

Comment: It can be proven that:  every NFA (backtracking (which can lead to ReDoS) may be needed) can be converted to a DFA (no backtracking is needed), which apparently is what sln did above and is what Go does in the background.

Comment: Golang uses RE2 just like Google Sheets, Gmail, G Suite. RE2 is a non-backtracking library with linear time execution - O(n)

Comment: @sln your suggested pattern does indeed avoid backtracking overflow, thanks.
It is not quite equivalent to my original pattern (e.g. does not match a--b) but a small mod sorted that  
`^(?:[a-z]-*)*[a-z]$`

Comment: @Andrew I don't believe that sln has converted an NFA to a DFA because backtracking is the algorithm used by the languages that can get "catastropic backtracking", and I see backtracking in the debugger on regex101.com when it reaches the end of a partial match, including using sln's regex.  That is a great tool!  
My understanding is that sln has removed the nested wildcarding that caused exponential backtracking on reaching the end of my example partial matches.  
But your comment led me to learn about NFA vs DFA so thanks for that.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413083).

Comment: @DaveDeasy Ok, I didn't look close enough. So you say `^(?:[a-z]-*)*[a-z]$` works then. Not surprised, the `[a-z]+` term will always be the culprit in a nested quant bactrack problem. Anytime you can minimize a dominant termed, open ended positive quant item it gives the engine no place to go.

Comment: @Adrian Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't support backtracking". It does appear to do backtracking at least in some cases. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/regexp/backtrack.go

Comment: @Mikel [as the official Wiki shows](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), all backtracking references are `NOT SUPPORTED`. [As the documentation states](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp), the `regexp` package implements [RE2](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), which explicitly does not support backtracking references. The Go stdlib RE syntax does not include support for any backreferences or lookarounds.

Comment: @Adrian Not supporting backreferences does not mean it doesn't do backtracking. I don't see any back references in the question, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the catastrophic backtracking warning can be safely ignored when using the regex in Go.

Go uses the RE2 algorithm for regex, and RE2 does not use backtracking so the problem does not arise in Go.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times has more information about alternative implementations for regex matching.
Go (RE2) has linear performance against input string length and regex string length: O(mn).

However other languages / libs that do use backtracking can have exponential running time, depending on the regex and the input string.
regex101.com shows the number of steps to run a regex against an input string and you can see the number of steps increase exponentially as you increase the string length for a regex like `(a*)*$` with a string like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaX`.  And the debugger on regex101.com can show the pattern match execution one step at a time, so you can see how backtracking has to handle an exponentially increasing number of alternatives.

[@sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15577665/sln) provided an alternative to my original regex that removed the exponential backtracking.
Simplifying the before/after regex to `a` and `X`, for input string `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaZ`
`^(a+X*)*a$` takes about 300,000 steps (doubling for each additional `a`) but
`^(aX*)*a$` takes about 100 steps

I don't know any general way to map a vulnerable regex to a safe regex - unless @sln cares to provide a service ;-)

The purpose of the original regex was to check that an input string contains only [a-z0-9] and `-` while starting and ending with [a-z0-9].
`a`, `a-b`, `ab--c`, `a-b--aa---bbb`, ...